# IIDR CDC Kafka subscription

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, cdc, ibm-infosphere, ibm-data-replication

For an enterprise wide data streaming platform implementation, we are using a confluent kafka and ibm iidr cdc .

Why the IIDR Management console has only two option to use zookeeper & rest proxy while configuring the subscription for kafka ?

[image]

From security perspective , it is not recommended at all to expose zookeeper . How can we just provide them broker endpoints to connect to kafka ? Or how can we implement IIDR confluent kafka connector ?
https://www.confluent.io/connector/ibm-data-replication/

How SSL can be implemented in IIDR CDC and Kafka ? any document links ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delay...

The following document describes several scenarios of IDR Kafka configuration. You can provide broker endpoints editing the /conf/kafkaproducer.properties (on the machine you installed IDR Kafka Agent).  If you do so, you still have to provide hostname and port number on MC GUI, but it will ignore them (you can provide fake data in those fields). It also explain some considerations on kerberized environments and on SSH connections.

Keep in mind that JRE provided with CDC has restricted security policy files, so, for using keys greater than 56 bytes (i.e. always), you need to download and upgrade them with unrestricted ones (they can be downloaded from IBM FixCentral page).

I hope this helps.

Referenced document:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/basic/anonymous/api/library/81dc842e-307f-486b-903a-71013bb159c0/document/6e39fdce-b6d0-4865-a4f0-345386a9783d/media/CDC%20Kafka%20-%20Installation%20and%20Configuration.pdf